# Why do I have to close the shell for my script to work? (writing to text files)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code in a .py file:

```
f = open('exampleTextFile.txt', 'w')
f.write('This is a sentence.')
f.close
```

I open it up and press F5 to run.

The IDLE shell opens up and runs the code without a hitch.  But then when I find the text file in my directory and open it up the text isn't there.  Then when I close the shell and reopen the text file the text now appears.  Why do I need to close the shell and what code can I write so that I don't have to do this?

I know the answer must be simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not closed properly. You forgot the parenthesis:

```
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent these mistakes by using the `open` context manager

```
with open('exampleTextFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('This is a sentence.')
# file automatically closed
```

This has the additional benefit that the file will be closed on errors too:

```
with open('exampleTextFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    raise Exception()
# file still closed
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is the recommended way of doing it.